# Cannot Resolve the Method addAll() and Clear()

Tags: android

I have written the code for getting the data fro sqlite, But As I use the two methods..

1. `addAll()` which is used to add data in list using sqlite
2. `clear()` which is used to clear the list
   both are not working

I go through this link but not get a satisfactory answer..
What is the Issue with this error..

Here is my Java File

```
{
ListView listView;
Activity activity;
Button btnAll;
DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
RecyclerView recyclerViewClients;
ClientRecyclerAdapter clientRecyclerAdapter;



@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.clients, container, false);

    btnAll=view.findViewById(R.id.searchall);
    clientRecyclerAdapter= new ClientRecyclerAdapter(listView,recyclerViewClients);

    databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(activity);
    listView=view.findViewById(R.id.Viewclients);
    getClientFromSqlite();

    btnAll.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Usman", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    return view;
}

private void getClientFromSqlite() {

    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            listView.clear();
            listView.addAll(databaseHelper.getAllOrderData());
            clientRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            clientRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }.execute();
}
}
```

Here is the gradle dependencies

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
```

Here is my Adapter Class

```
{

private List<GetSetOrders> listOrders;
Context mContext;
RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
View itemView;

public ClientRecyclerAdapter(ListView listOrders, RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    this.listOrders = (List<GetSetOrders>) listOrders;
    mRecyclerView=recyclerView;
}

@Override
public ClientViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    mContext= parent.getContext();
    itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.items_products_table, parent, false);

    return new ClientViewHolder(itemView);
}
/**
 * ViewHolder class
 */
public class ClientViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    //public AppCompatTextView ID;
    public TextView lblPName;
    public TextView lblTrade;
    public TextView lblRetail;
    public TextView lblSubCategary;
    public TextView lblCompany;
    RelativeLayout layout;

    public ClientViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);


        lblPName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lblPName);
        lblTrade = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lblTrade);
        lblRetail = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lblRetail);
        lblSubCategary = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lblSubCategary);
        lblCompany = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lblCompany);
        layout = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.listprod);
    }
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ClientViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    holder.lblPName.setText(listOrders.get(position).getNAME());
    holder.lblTrade.setText(listOrders.get(position).getORDERCODE());
    holder.lblRetail.setText(listOrders.get(position).getRETAIL());
    holder.lblSubCategary.setText(listOrders.get(position).getSUBCATAGARY());
    holder.lblCompany.setText(listOrders.get(position).getCOMPANY());
    holder.layout.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            displayingAlertDialog(position);
            return false;
        }
    });

}

private void displayingAlertDialog(int position) {
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    Log.v(ClientRecyclerAdapter.class.getSimpleName(),""+listOrders.size());
    return listOrders.size();

}
```

}

```
 7 11:34:14.224 2021-2021/com.example.tablewithlist E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$TabView.updateBackgroundDrawable
05-17 11:34:14.856 2021-2021/com.example.tablewithlist E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.tablewithlist.ClientRecyclerAdapter cannot be cast to android.widget.ListAdapter
        at com.example.tablewithlist.Clients.onCreateView(Clients.java:41)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2439)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1460)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1784)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1852)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:802)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2625)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2411)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2366)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:2243)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:654)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:168)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1244)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1092)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1622)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:617)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:399)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:143)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1390)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:681)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
```

Comment: attach the ClientRecyclerAdapter file code.

Comment: Because `ListView` does not have these methods you are probably confused `List` Collection with `ListView`.. And Why are you having `ListView` and `RecyclerView` Both ?

Comment: Where is the adapter for listview? What are you setting there?

Comment: `ListView` is not `List`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't attached adapter with listView. Replace your onCreateView with this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.clients, container, false);

    btnAll=view.findViewById(R.id.searchall);
    clientRecyclerAdapter= new ClientRecyclerAdapter(listView,recyclerViewClients);

    databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(activity);
    listView=view.findViewById(R.id.Viewclients);

    //missing line
    listView.setAdapter(clientRecyclerAdapter);

    getClientFromSqlite();

    btnAll.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Usman", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

Another thing highlighted by ADM is you need to write addAll and clear method inside adapter class.

Replace your adapter with this one:

```
{

    private List<GetSetOrders> listOrders;
    Context mContext;
    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    View itemView;

    public ClientRecyclerAdapter(ListView listOrders, RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        this.listOrders = (List<GetSetOrders>) listOrders;
        mRecyclerView = recyclerView;
    }

    @Override
    public ClientViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        mContext = parent.getContext();
        itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.items_products_table, parent, false);

        return new ClientViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    public void addAll(ArrayList<GetSetOrders> listOrders) {
        this.listOrders = listOrders;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void clear() {
        this.listOrders.clear();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    /**
     * ViewHolder class
     */
    public class ClientViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        //public AppCompatTextView ID;
        public TextView lblPName;
        public TextView lblTrade;
        public TextView lblRetail;
        public TextView lblSubCategary;
        public TextView lblCompany;
        RelativeLayout layout;

        public ClientViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);


            lblPName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lblPName);
            lblTrade = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lblTrade);
            lblRetail = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lblRetail);
            lblSubCategary = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lblSubCategary);
            lblCompany = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lblCompany);
            layout = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.listprod);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ClientViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        holder.lblPName.setText(listOrders.get(position).getNAME());
        holder.lblTrade.setText(listOrders.get(position).getORDERCODE());
        holder.lblRetail.setText(listOrders.get(position).getRETAIL());
        holder.lblSubCategary.setText(listOrders.get(position).getSUBCATAGARY());
        holder.lblCompany.setText(listOrders.get(position).getCOMPANY());
        holder.layout.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                displayingAlertDialog(position);
                return false;
            }
        });

    }

    private void displayingAlertDialog(int position) {
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        Log.v(ClientRecyclerAdapter.class.getSimpleName(), "" + listOrders.size());
        return listOrders.size();

    }
}
```

Comment: Issue remains the same after applying this

Comment: what have you done with your  listView.clear(); and             listView.addAll(databaseHelper.getAllOrderData());
methods?

Comment: I have added my adapter class

Comment: have you replaced listView.clear() with clientRecyclerAdapter.clear() and same for listView.addAll with clientRecyclerAdapter.addAll?

Comment: No i have not replaced

Comment: After replacing the error is still on the clear and addall

Comment: yes because you need to create methods in your adapter and also have to add functionality in them.

Comment: I have added them in adapter class but the result is also same there

Comment: I have added my adapter class in the question, Can you guide me where to put these methods and How?

Comment: I have added the adapter in answer.

Comment: the adapter is for recyclerview not for listview. so review listview from everywhere and user recyclerview. Attach adapter with it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the issue.

```
listView.clear();
listView.addAll(databaseHelper.getAllOrderData());
```

`listView` don't have any kind of these methods. Indeed `List` or `ArrayList` have these methods. So you must create instance of List by

> List listOf = new ArrayList<>();

and then use

```
listOf.clear();
listOf.addAll(databaseHelper.getAllOrderData());
```

Where `DataType` will be any kind of `String` ,`Model Class` or `Integer` etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your listView don't have a method yet. You can create instance of the list by

```
ArrayList<?> data = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList());
```

? :datatype which can be **String**, **Integer** etc.